# BEM Post CSS Stylelint plugin cannot ignore "*:last-child" selector

Tags: css, postcss, bem, stylelint

I have an Angular project in which BEM CSS methodology is being used. I have stylelint set up to lint my CSS. I also have incorporated the [stylelint-selector-bem-pattern](https://github.com/simonsmith/stylelint-selector-bem-pattern) plugin to lint my selectors to ensure they adhere to a custom BEM pattern. Note that stylelint-selector-bem-pattern is a wrapper around [postcss-bem-linter](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter), so it has all the same customisable options.

The problem I have is that I need to add a particular pattern to the `ignoreSelectors` list, but I can't get it work.

I need to ignore the use of `*:last-child`, as per below:

`.example__selector *:last-child.`

My config looks like this:

```
"plugin/selector-bem-pattern": {
  "implicitComponents": "projects/test/src/lib/**/*.scss",
  "componentSelectors": {
    "initial": "^.test-([-?a-z]|[\\-\\-?a-z])+"
  },
  "ignoreSelectors" : [
    "^.+:last-child"
  ]
  "ignoreCustomProperties": [
    "^\\-\\-[-?a-z]"
  ]
}
```

Using [RexExr](https://regexr.com/), I can see that the RegEx `^.+:last-child` matches the text.

However, I still get this error when I run stylelint:

```
6:3  ✖  Invalid component selector ".example__selector *:last-child"  plugin/selector-bem-pattern
```

Comment: It would be good also to report a bug may to the source project here by opening a new issue https://github.com/postcss/postcss-bem-linter/issues

Comment: Thanks, if it's not something I've got wrong in the config I'll report it as a bug.